# Класс для просмотра файла в текстовом окне

Tags: c#, wpf, filestream

Доброго дня.
Возникло противоречие про класс, который позволяет просматривать файлы в текстовом окне.

Этим классом ведь является класс File? Или им является FileStream?
Используя File у меня получилось открыть файл методом ReadAllText, а вот FileStream схожих методов не имеет и я предполагаю, что он явно не для открытия файлов во что либо.

Второй вопрос, каким образом можно корректно открыть документы например типа docx, чтобы его содержание имело привычный вид(как при открытии в textbox например txt файлов), а не перекодированный символами.

Comment: Попробуйте копнуть в строну WordprocessingDocument . https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/office/ff478255.aspx

Comment: File и FileStream - классы обеспечивающие доступ к содержимому файла, отображение не входит в их функции. А по поводу обработки файлов Word, есть разные варианты, interop, OOXML и т.д. А если за деньги, то можно посмотреть SyncFusion и DevExpress, у них вроде были готовые контролы для этого.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Класс File содержит в себе набор функций для упрощения выполнения типовых операций над файлами. Например, функция [File.ReadAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368(v=vs.110).aspx) открывает файл, если возможно, определяет кодировку используемую при сохранении текста в этот файл, читает его содержимое переводя его в текст, закрывает файл, возвращает текст. Все эти действия можно было бы закодировать вручную, если бы не было функции ReadAllText.

Класс FileStream представляет собой открытый для чтения или записи файл, и предоставляет намного больше возможностей для работы с файлом, нежели класс File. Эту работу надо закодировать вручную. Например, вот так выглядит код, выполняющий ту же самую работу что и ReadAllText.

```
public static string ReadAllText(string filePath) {
    using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(filePath)) {
        var encoding = new UTF8Encoding(true);
        var reader = new StreamReader(stream, encoding);
        return reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Такой подход удобен когда необходимо сделать нечто большее чем просто вычитать весь текст из файла.

Что касается файлов *.docx, то они содержат совсем не текст, а документ содержащий кроме текста еще и разметку форматирования, изображения, таблицы, и прочее. Для того чтобы сохранить такой документ в файл, используется проприетарный формат.

Microsoft опубликовала спецификацию форматов для всех документов линейки Microsoft Office, и ее можно скачать с этой страницы: [Technical Documents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc313105(v=office.12).aspx). Но одна только спецификация формата DOC - это PDF файл на почти 20 мегабайт. Поэтому для того чтобы прочитать текст из *.docx файла лучше использовать специальные библиотеки, вроде тех, которые посоветовали в комментариях [And](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/209349/and) и [rdorn](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/198316/rdorn):

[Пример использования Word Processing (Open XML SDK)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/office/ff478255.aspx)

[Пример использования Microsoft.Office.Interop](http://mantascode.com/c-how-to-parse-the-text-content-from-microsoft-word-document/)

[Описание компонента RichEditDocumentService от DevExpress](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/clsDevExpressXtraRichEditRichEditDocumentServertopic)

[Описание компонента WordDocument от Syncfusion](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/docio)

Comment: я слышал, мелкомягкие выкладывали в открытый доступ документацию по этому своему формату, они хотели его стандартизировать в ISO. Правда, у людей, которые пытались что-либо написать используя эту документацию появились претензии к ее качеству из-за большого количества "белых мест" и неточностей.

Comment: @Bulson, вы совершенно правы. Мне удалось даже отыскать эту документацию. Похоже, вот то о чем вы говорите: [Office File Formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc313118(v=office.12).aspx). Я добавил это в свой ответ.

Answer (score 1):

1) `FileStream` как и `IsolatedStorageStream` и `MemoryStream` и `NetworkStream` относятся к так называемым "Backing store streams", т.е. работают с информацией как с последовательностью байтов привязанной к определенной цели: файловой системе или памяти процесса или сетевому ресурсу. Для работы с определенным форматом данных, т.е. когда требуется внести какую-то осмысленность в эту последовательность байт ее "оборачивают" в так называемый "Stream adapter", к которому относятся: хотим текст (`StreamReader`, `StreamWriter`), хотим базовые типы (`int,float,string`) тогда (`BinaryReader`, `BinaryWriter`), хотим XML (`XmlReader`, `XmlWriter`).

2) Вы можете взять любой файл типа .docx и изменить его расширение на .zip, тогда вы сможете заглянуть "под капот" этому формату. И увидите, что он состоит из нескольких каталогов с вложенными файлами в формате xml. Отсюда следует вывод: либо вы занимаетесь написанием собственной библиотеки по работе с этим проприетарным форматом, либо, что вам советует в комментариях @rdorn, покупаете готовую библиотеку для работы с этим форматом.